# How to use Gradle with stand-alone Android SDK?

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I use a stand-alone Android SDK with no IDE. When I create a new project its root directory contains files such as **build.xml** and **ant.properties**, so I have to use **Ant** to compile my projects.

How can I use **Gradle** tool instead of **Ant** to compile my projects?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just written a blog post on this subject exactly. Please have a look at [The Holy Gradle](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/holy-gradle-setting-android-build-build-server-part-1/). Next week I will publish the second part, which will detail the steps for setting up such an environment.